# How to use If and Goto in Table loop?

Tags: list-manipulation, procedural-programming, education

I have the following code,

```
j=0;
Table[{Label[1], j = j + 1, i, If[j == 2, Goto[1], Continue]}, {i, 1,10}]
```

which does not work; I get `does not find Label[1]` and for other initial values of `j`, I get the following result:

> {Label[1], 3, 1, Continue}, {Label[1], 4, 2, Continue}, {Label[1], 5, 
>         3, Continue}, {Label[1], 6, 4, Continue}, {Label[1], 7, 5, 
>         Continue}, {Label[1], 8, 6, Continue}, {Label[1], 9, 7, 
>         Continue}, {Label[1], 10, 8, Continue}, {Label[1], 11, 9, 
>         Continue}, {Label[1], 12, 10, Continue}}

What I intended to do was: when `j` is equal to `2`, the `i` in loop does not change  until `j` gets added by one and then it continues. Could you please help me where I made mistake?
Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain what output you expect to see? There is probably a much simpler way to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 5):

There are easier ways to "skip a beat". For example:

```
Table[If[i == 2, Nothing, i], {i, 1, 11}]
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this does what you want?

```
j = 0;
Table[Label[1]; j = j + 1; i; If[j == 2, Goto[1]]; j, {i, 1, 10}]
```

> {1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}

The main problems where the commas; they have to be semicoli. Notice also that the braces `{` and `}` in Mathematica are used as delimiters for lists and not for code blocks  -- contrary to C. For code blocks, just use parentheses `(` and `)`.

`Continue` is not really necessary here. If you insist on using it, please use `Continue[]` instead (notice the brackets).

Comment: thank you, but what I wanted, was when j=2 goes back without changing i, in this case when j=2, it goes back without changing i could you please advise me in this respect>

Comment: @kmsin I don't understand your question. When `j` equals `2`, the proposed algorithm _does_ jump back to `Label[1]` without changing `i`.

Comment: Ah, yes. Thank you so much Herik, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: could you please tell me what the problem is with this one? pos = Table[
  Label[2]; {x[i] = 20*RandomReal[], y[i] = 20*RandomReal[]}, 
  Table [If[Sqrt [(x[i] - x[j])^2 + (y[i] - y[j])^2] < 4, 
    Goto[2]   ], {j, 1, i - 1}], {i, 1, 10}]

Answer (score 1):

`If` already does what you want:

```
j = 0;
Table[j++; If[j == 2, j++; j, j], {i, 1, 10}]
```

Answer (score 1):

A different way of doing this might be:

```
Complement[Table[j, {j, 1, 11}], {2}]
```

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful